# Using the same order as a subquery without the results getting sorted unnecessarily

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, window-functions

I have a large table over which I want to execute some window functions by scanning over an index and I want to stop scanning and produce the row when one of a number of conditions hold involving these aggregates (so `WHERE ... LIMIT 1` is out of question, since I can't have window functions inside the `WHERE`).

Let me expand further on my concrete case:

Here's my `events` table:

```
=> \d events
                      Table "public.events"
   Column   |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 block      | character varying |           | not null | 
 chainid    | bigint            |           | not null | 
 height     | bigint            |           | not null | 
 idx        | bigint            |           | not null | 
 module     | character varying |           | not null | 
 modulehash | character varying |           | not null | 
 name       | character varying |           | not null | 
 params     | jsonb             |           | not null | 
 paramtext  | character varying |           | not null | 
 qualname   | character varying |           | not null | 
 requestkey | character varying |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (block, idx, requestkey)
    "events_height_chainid_idx" btree (height DESC, chainid, idx)
```

After much experimentation, I've arrived at a query that returns exactly the row I want and it also produces exactly the query plan that I'm envisioning:

```
=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY height DESC, block, requestkey, idx) as scan_num
       , count(*) FILTER (WHERE qualname ILIKE '%transfer%') OVER
           ( ORDER BY height DESC, block, requestkey, idx 
             ROWS BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
           ) AS foundCnt
  FROM events
  ORDER BY height DESC, block, requestkey, idx 
) as scanned_events
WHERE foundCnt = 3 OR scan_num = 100000
LIMIT 1                                             
;
                                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1065.81..1400.34 rows=1 width=397) (actual time=0.095..0.096 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Subquery Scan on scanned_events  (cost=1065.81..165535223.46 rows=494824 width=397) (actual time=0.095..0.095 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: ((scanned_events.foundcnt = 3) OR (scanned_events.scan_num = 100000))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 2
         ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1065.81..164791126.56 rows=49606460 width=397) (actual time=0.089..0.094 rows=3 loops=1)
               ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1065.81..163550965.06 rows=49606460 width=389) (actual time=0.081..0.083 rows=4 loops=1)
                     ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=1065.81..162434819.71 rows=49606460 width=381) (actual time=0.076..0.076 rows=5 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: events.height DESC, events.block, events.requestkey, events.idx
                           Presorted Key: events.height
                           Full-sort Groups: 1  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 56kB  Peak Memory: 56kB
                           ->  Index Scan using events_height_chainid_idx on events  (cost=0.56..158424783.98 rows=49606460 width=381) (actual time=0.015..0.035 rows=53 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.112 ms
 Execution Time: 0.128 ms
(13 rows)
```

Here's what this query is trying to achieve: Scan through the `events` table counting the number of rows whose `qualname` contains `'transfers'` and return the row as soon as you find the 3rd match **OR** you end up scanning 100000 rows.

So, my high-level intention is to look for some condition (involving a moving aggregate) but I want to put an upper bound on how many rows I'm willing to fetch. But if I happen to find what I'm looking for quickly, I also don't want to go through the rest of those 100000 rows unnecessarily (similar to the query plan above, where it ends up scanning just 53 rows).

If you inspect the query plan, this query is doing exactly what I want, but it has a serious flaw: It's not guaranteed to produce the correct result, it just happens to do it since the correct result is produced by the most natural way to execute the query, but the top-level `SELECT` has no `ORDER BY` clause, so Postgres could in theory execute it in a different way and end up returning any one row that happens to return `foundCnt = 3`.

In order to remedy this flaw, I've tried the following:

```
=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY height DESC, block, requestkey, idx) as scan_num
       , count(*) FILTER (WHERE qualname ILIKE '%transfer%') OVER
           ( ORDER BY height DESC, block, requestkey, idx 
             ROWS BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
           ) AS foundCnt
  FROM events
  ORDER BY height DESC, block, requestkey, idx 
) as scanned_events
WHERE foundCnt = 3 OR scan_num = 100000
ORDER BY height DESC, block, requestkey, idx 
LIMIT 1
;
                                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=16173553.41..16173571.35 rows=1 width=397) (actual time=86703.480..88314.937 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Subquery Scan on scanned_events  (cost=16173553.41..25051383.19 rows=494821 width=397) (actual time=86435.692..88047.148 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: ((scanned_events.foundcnt = 3) OR (scanned_events.scan_num = 100000))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 2
         ->  WindowAgg  (cost=16173553.41..24307291.63 rows=49606104 width=397) (actual time=86435.682..88047.143 rows=3 loops=1)
               ->  WindowAgg  (cost=16173553.41..23067139.03 rows=49606104 width=389) (actual time=86435.662..88047.120 rows=4 loops=1)
                     ->  Gather Merge  (cost=16173553.41..21951001.69 rows=49606104 width=381) (actual time=86435.630..88047.085 rows=5 loops=1)
                           Workers Planned: 2
                           Workers Launched: 2
                           ->  Sort  (cost=16172553.39..16224226.41 rows=20669210 width=381) (actual time=86147.622..86147.642 rows=106 loops=3)
                                 Sort Key: events.height DESC, events.block, events.requestkey, events.idx
                                 Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 6535240kB
                                 Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 6503568kB
                                 Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 6506736kB
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..2852191.10 rows=20669210 width=381) (actual time=43.151..4135.334 rows=16430767 loops=3)
 Planning Time: 0.353 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 16
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 3.412 ms, Inlining 105.447 ms, Optimization 204.392 ms, Emission 87.327 ms, Total 400.578 ms
 Execution Time: 89345.338 ms
(21 rows)
```

Now it ends up scanning the entire table, even though I've just explicitly specified what it was already doing. I've tried many variations on the latter query, such as moving the subquery to a CTE or ordering the outer `SELECT` by `scan_num`, ordering both `SELECT`s by `scan_num`, only ordering the outer `SELECT` by `height DESC, block, requestkey, idx`. I honestly lost track of the variations I've already tried, but as soon as I have an `ORDER BY` clause on the outer `SELECT`, Postgres ends up scanning the entire table.

So, my question is: Is there any way to achieve what I want without relying on fragile semantics (like the query that does exactly what I want). I.e. what would be the correct way to write a Postgres query that will scan a bounded number of rows and return as soon as a condition (involving window functions) is satisfied.

---

### Addressing the comments

@nbk suggested trying to add an index on `height DESC, block, requestkey, idx`, i.e. the exact order we're looking for. Even though I want to avoid adding that index because I'm happy with the performance of my first query (so the index shouldn't be necessary), I still tried it, but it didn't change the query plan of the second query at all, it doesn't use any indexes anyway. It just made the first query slighly faster as expected, since that one does use indexes.

Comment: what happens when you remove the order by in the inner select as it is superfluous

Comment: @nbk its presence or absence doesn't seem to have any effect on the query plans, which isn't surprising since it's superfluous

Comment: and when you add an index with the four columns

Comment: @nbk see my edit at the end of my question, the index didn't help

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: ah i see your problem the temporary table that you create has no index, independent if the original table has one, so your sort will not utilize it. , but yu have with the index some performance advantage

Comment: @jjanes PostgreSQL 14.5